# Android: How to make background darker or lighter?

Tags: android, view, background-color

I want my app to be able to use an onSwipeListener, which I have coded, to make the background's color darker or lighter based on the direction of their swipe. If the user swipes right, it gets brighter and left, it gets darker.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
    @Override
    public void onSwipeLeft() {
          //Make Darker
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipeRight(){
          //Make Lighter
    }
```

is my code, but I'm having trouble understanding how I would change the color outside of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in part before so here's the link explaining [onSwipeTouchListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)

I know this doesn't explain changing the background of the view that can be simply done in this example:

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eiIB.png)

[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpesG.png)